# Best tool for QoS testing

Tags: networking, testing, qos

The problem is that, i cant find good tool for QoS configuration testing(linux). I have some switches and configured QoS on them. Installed two PC's with wireshark for watching whether switches are colouring packets, so thats ok. But how to check bandwidth allocation? I know iperf, it can set ToS . But may be there is some special utility?

Comment: So what i get until now:
-wireshark for ToS-Diffserv
-iperf for emulating udp|tcp activity

Answer (score 1):

Bit low-tech but we test ours with big httpgets from known sources - we do lots of these and average them out.

Answer (score 0):

The real way would be with a [hardware tool like Ixia pumping your switches](http://www.ixiacom.com/library/test_plans/display?skey=qos).
You could check vendors to get it on loan for testing if this is a one time requirement.